# button click issue in Ext js

Tags: extjs, logic

i have small query i created four text fields and one button,in text fields i gave property  **allowblank:true** if user enter shows error message,it's working perfect.If the click the button the inserted perfect,after that the textboxes becomes empty it's showing blank errormessage.If iam using **Allowblank:false**  it's working fine.but i require if user not enter in that textbox i need to show error message.

how can i resolve this issue.Any one can share any idea to me.

Comment: are you using an Ext form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to do that :

- **1st** : use a Ext.form.Panel with all your textfield and your button inside. The `allowBlank : false` property will check if your texfields are empty and if they are the button will stay disabled if it's got the property `formBind : true`. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/binoss/ubLcycht/
- **2nd** : use a normal Ext.panel.Panel the same way than with Form.Panel, but you will have to handle the click event on button to check that all your texfields are not empty, and display a Error Message. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/binoss/yz339z7w/

Comment: Hi :) If my answer is OK for you feel free to mark it as "Accepted"